# Movement with setOnKeyPressed and setOnKeyReleased

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote some code to control the movement of a small rectangle on the screen with JavaFX. Basically, I move the player smoothly in the game loop with these codes:

(P.S: player is my object)

```
player.setTranslateX(player.getTranslateX() + player.velocityX);
player.setTranslateY(player.getTranslateY() + player.velocityY);
```

And these are the key bindings:

```
myScene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
   Thread t1;

   t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         switch(e.getCode()) {
            case A:
            player.velocityX = -1;
            break;

            case D:
            player.velocityX = 1;
            break;

            case W:
            player.velocityY = -1;
            break;

            case S:
            player.velocityY = 1;
            break;
         }
      }
   }); 
   t1.start();
})
```

Key releases:

```
myScene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
   Thread t2;

   t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         switch(e.getCode()) {
            case A:
            player.velocityX = 0;
            break;

            case D:
            player.velocityX = 0;
            break;

            case W:
            player.velocityY = 0;
            break;

            case S:
            player.velocityY = 0;
            break;
         }
      }
   });
   t2.start();
})
```

It is working fine but there is a bug that when I press multiple keys at the same time and release one of them, the objects stops moving until I release my finger off the key and press the key again. Now I know it has something to do with the ambiguity concept but I've hit a brick wall and I'm open for ideas.

Comment: you should use an infinite loop to check for key presses and releases.

Comment: I tried creating an AnimationTimer but still the same.

Comment: I meant an infinite while loop

Comment: I created an infinite while(true) loop right after primaryStage.show() in the typical JavaFX @Override start() method and transferred everything in AnimationTimer handle method to there. But now it's stuck at game window. Where do you suggest i put the while loop?

Comment: put the run function in the loop

Comment: I implemented it and the issue remains the same... I know I'm asking too much but can you have a look at the code for me? It's driving me insane... main.java -> https://pastebin.com/hWmFqD1E  /// sprite.java -> https://pastebin.com/v5uczhsp  /// screenandtiles.java -> https://pastebin.com/4AtSD5MA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this problem before when writing a game just like you're writing.

After a bunch of debugging, it looked like the issue is actually related to the code you're writing, but rather to the library itself. It seems that if you hold down multiple keys, the buffer of received key presses gets "jammed" and it doesn't respond until you let go and press again.

One workaround for this on Mac is to run the following command in terminal:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

This seemed to fix the behavior. For Windows, we weren't able to find anything to fix the issue.

Comment: I figured out a way to transition from A to D by adding a flag like this: 1.) set flag to initially false. 2.) case A:
        if(flag2) {
         return;
        }
        player.velocityX = -1;
        break; /// But it doesn't work for transition from D to A though... Thanks for the response.